# Как разбить текст на отдельные предложения?

Tags: python

Как разбить текст на отдельные предложения? Вариант со splitlines() не подходить, так как текст может быть записан в одну строку.

Answer (score 3):

Выражение игнорирует
1980г.
100руб.
100р.
100коп.
100к.
и.т.д.
и.т.п.
а также совмещенные знаки препинания.
Код здесь
http://ideone.com/pNpffv

Comment: @ReinRaus: мне кажется, лучше имплементировать такую семантику: после знака/ов препинания должен быть пробел, последующее слово должно быть с большой буквы. Год и цена могут вполне _заканчивать_ предложение...

Comment: Э, так у нас же каждое новое предложение начинается с большой буквы? Почему бы не искать то место, где стоит точка и идет заглавная буква? Конечно, есть исключения, вроде имен, городов и т.п. - но это уже в целый проект выливается. Тьфу, дублирую @VladD ну да пофиг.

Comment: **UPD** Исправил вчерашние ошибки, оказывается проблема была не в плохом самочувствии, а в [этой проблеме](http://hashcode.ru/questions/197474/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Comment: Интересно, а вложенные предложения могут быть?

Поясню, есть предложение, в нем начинается цитата (в кавычках. Или скобках, как здесь), а потом оно продолжается.

Как такую фигню разбирать? 

По идее это вопрос на форум Русский Язык, но регистрироваться там (по поводу малозначащей для меня проблемы) неохота.

Answer (score 0):

```
parts = all_text.split('.')
```

Comment: Тогда уж хоть

      re.compile("[.!?\n]").split(all_text)
      re.split("[.!?\n]", all_text)

Comment: Как быть с троеточием?

Comment: Если голодному дать рыбу - он наестся один раз, а если научить ловить рыбу - он будет сыт всегда…

Comment: Да просто интересно как в регулярке будет выглядеть. А так полностью согласен.

Comment: Наверно как-то так "([.!?\n]|...){1}"

Comment: только (...|[.!?\n]), а то он первую же точку на радостях схватит

Comment: Так должно быть получше с составными разделителями:  

    re.split("\\b[.!?\\n]+(?=\\s)", all_text)

Comment: @moden `...` называется многоточием (по крайней мере называлось, когда я учился в школе). Во-вторых, есть и такой знак `?!?`. Можно подойти к заданию "творчески" (удалять пустые строки). 

     filter(lambda x:not re.match("^\s*$", x), re.split("[!.?\n]", all_text)

Правда есть подозрение, что знаки препинания в результирующем списке должны присутствовать. И тогда -- просто поиск по шаблону `[^!.?\n]+[!.?\n]+`. Что тоже не даёт 100% правильного результата "В 1998г. был дефолт".

Comment: Также не сто́ит забывать про UTF-8 где есть «…» одним символом… И, наверняка, не только…

Comment: Спасибо за исправление. Но слово "троеточие" тоже допустимо в просторечии.

Comment: @ReinRaus: а ещё А. С. Пушкин

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "Properties are a little different. They need a special declaration since they're handled in a very different way. (Hmmmm... I may have figured out an obvious way around that, but I want to get this out the door first.) Here's how you'd mock out calls to a property. Note that unlike other calls, all the calls to an overridden property must be played back in order."

def srtip_sent(str_):
    separators = ['.', '?', '!']
    start = 0
    s_split = []
    for i in range(len(str_)):
        if s[i] in separators:
            s_split.append(str_[start:i+1])
            start = i + 1
    return map(lambda s: s.strip(), s_split)

srtip_sent(s)
['Properties are a little different.', "They need a special declaration since they're handled in a very different way.", '(Hmmmm.', '.', '.', 'I may have figured out an obvious way around that, but I want to get this out the door first.', ") Here's how you'd mock out calls to a property.", 'Note that unlike other calls, all the calls to an overridden property must be played back in order.']
```

Не очень корректно работает с составными знаками, например с троеточием.

Comment: ... а ещё с инициалами, типа `А. С. Пушкин`. А ещё с внутренними знаками препинания, наподобие `"Что за хрень?" -- поинтересовалась Алиса.`