# Java. Поиск предложений в тексте

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть большой текст. Как можно получить массив предложений используя регулярное выражение? Пример: "какой - то текст и т.д." концом предложения считать "." или "!" или "?"

Comment: Задача не решаема в общем случае без искусственного интеллекта. Возможно этот вопрос Вам поможет: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/197142/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String string = "qwe.zzz!aa ? 11123 ?";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([^.!?]+)").matcher(string);
while (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Out

```
qwe
zzz
aa 
 11123
```

**UPDATE**

Регулярка для сохранения знака ( см. первый комментарий)

```
String string = "qwe.zzz!aa ? 11123 ?";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([^.!?]+[.!?])").matcher(string);
while (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Другая проблема, мне нужно, что бы строки сохранялись вместе со знаком в конце предложения. Как это можно реализовать??

Comment: смотри регулярку в апдейте

Comment: Ошибочное выражение `[.|!|?]`

Comment: Почему данное выражение является ошибочным?

Comment: Потому что `|` - не альтернатива.

Comment: @ReinRaus да, верно. Ошибся. Надо без | писать в квадратных скобках